# "А так(,) вполне сносно". Запятая после "так"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая после "так" в данном случае?

**А так вполне сносно, вот.**

Answer (score 6):

Сносно (как? в каком случае?) - так. Обстоятельство, условий для обособления действительно нет.

Comment: А если бы не было обстоятельством?
"Когда он делал это по-другому, было плохо, а так (как сейчас) - вполне сносно". Я даже не могу понять, откуда сама идея насчет запятой взялась. 



Answer (score 1):

Если что и нужно, так это тире, но не обязательно. Для запятой не вижу никаких оснований, даже интонационных.

Но вообще-то на всякий случай хорошо бы контекст посмотреть, фраза уж очень разговорная.